# Invalide OpCode and php sort function

Tags: php, sorting, opcode, eaccelerator

Didn't change anything lately but I started to get the infamouse PHP Fatal error:  `Invalid opcode 153/1/8`

a small php -v showed:

```
PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze17 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 23 2013 15:06:16) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with eAccelerator v1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 2004-2012 eAccelerator, by eAccelerator
```

To be honest, I wasn't aware we used eAccelerator before. I think the hoster upgraded php or changed something in php.ini because I'm sure I didn't touch the code meanwhile..

Anyway my question is: since the Fatal error is shown on the line where I have:

```
uasort($tabWsFull, function($a, $b) { 
  return $b['bk'] - $a['bk']; 
});
```

Is there something I can do to fix from within the code ? (without deactivating eAcceleator) maybe rewriting the uasort function ?

All the help is welcome, thx for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but still try

```
function mySort($a,$b){
  return $b['bk'] - $a['bk']; 
}

uasort($tabWsFull,'mySort');
```

Comment: Yeah that was what I just did actually and it worked fine. Thx for your answer.